# Launch fullscreen from outside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to be able to launch an iframe into full screen from a button outside of the iframe. The button I have can launch the page into full screen , but im unsure and unable to find how to do the same for the iframe.

Code

HTML BUTTON :

```
<button onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);" class="sexyButton">Launch Fullscreen</button>
```

JS :

```
function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: An iframe needs the allowfullscreen="true" attribute, not sure if it works cross domain

Comment: the iframe has the atribute on it . The code I have launches the page that the iframe is on into fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a link which links to the iframe source opening in a new tab?  You could also use take a look at this article too as it has some good examples.

Here's it all together:

```
<script>
<!--
function fullwin(){
window.open("YOURURLHERE.COM","bfs","fullscreen,scrollbars")
}
//-->
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" onClick="fullwin()" value="Open Full Screen Window">
</form>
```

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470521

A basic google search brings up another way of doing it here:

[Building an amazing fullscreen mobile experience](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/)

Comment: But that doesn't answer the problem at hand. The question is how do you launch it.

Comment: I really wanted to not open a popup . could i not use the api . document.body.requestFullscreen();

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to find an answer.

```
// Find the right method, call on correct element
function fullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function fullwin(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('ppt');
fullScreen(canvas);
}
```